# Django ORM : Filter to get the users whose birthday week is in n days

Tags: python, django, datetime, orm

I am trying to make a django query which is supposed to gave me the users whose birthday week is in n days.

I already tried to use the __week operator but it's not working as expected :

```
    now = timezone.now().date()
    first_day_of_next_week = (now + timedelta(days=(7 - now.weekday())))

    if now + relativedelta(days=n_days) == first_day_of_next_week:
        return qs.filter(birth_date__isnull=False, birth_date__week=first_day_of_next_week.strftime("%V"))
```

Indeed, for example if a user is born the 24/06/1997, the 24/06 is not on the same week nbr in 1997 than in 2023, so it's giving me unexpected results.

Could you help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

Range filter
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#range

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()
start_week_date = date - datetime.timedelta(date.weekday())
end_week_date = start_week_date + datetime.timedelta(7)
qs = qs.filter(birth_date__range=[start_week, end_week])
```

it will get current week records

Comment: It's not working because the birth_date year is 1997 in my example and the dates used for your example have current year

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution for this :

```
    now = timezone.now().date()
    first_day_of_next_week = (now + timedelta(days=(7 - now.weekday())))

    # If next week starts in n days
    if now + relativedelta(days=value) == first_day_of_next_week:

        next_week_days = []
        next_week_month = None

        next_week_days_month2 = []
        next_week_month2 = None

        # Store each day nbr of next week and the month number
        # If there are days from an other month in next week, store them separately
        for i in range(7):
            current_day = first_day_of_next_week + relativedelta(days=i)

            if current_day.month == first_day_of_next_week.month:
                next_week_days.append(current_day.day)
                next_week_month = current_day.month
            else:
                next_week_days_month2.append(current_day.day)
                next_week_month2 = current_day.month

        from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay, ExtractMonth

        # Extract day and month of birth date
        # Compare them with the day and months of the next week
        users = qs.annotate(
            birth_date_day=ExtractDay('birth_date'),
            birth_date_month=ExtractMonth('birth_date')
        ).filter(
            Q(birth_date_day__in=next_week_days, birth_date_month=next_week_month) |
            Q(birth_date_day__in=next_week_days_month2, birth_date_month=next_week_month2)
        )

        return users

    return qs.none()
```